# Shrinking root device size after install?

Tags: windows, kubuntu, format

I installed ubuntu after installing a fresh copy of windows. Unfortunately I accidentally clicked on one of the pre-set options and did not get a chance to manually specify the size of my root partition and swap space. I had 350GB of unallocated space and ubuntu made the entire 350GB the root drive (.ext4). Seeing as using fdisk or resize2fs inside ubuntu would be bad as this is the root drive, would it be ok if I used a windows based partitioning program to resize the root partition? I want to shrink the root partition down to 100GB and have the remaining 250GB as a NTFS parition that I can use in windows and mount on ubuntu.

I know this is a lot of text but thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3):

You can resize the partition after booting from the Ubuntu live CD (or USB stick - in other words, the same medium you installed it from).

Using a windows-based partitioning program would most likely destroy all data on the linux partition (unless you're talking about some specific program which is explicitly aware of ext4 and knows how to resize it)